# How to diagnose compatibility issues that work in Windows 7 but not in Wndows 10

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, wordperfect

So, I've got a mother-in-law who loves WordPerfect 11 (Eleven shall be the version of WP, and the version of WP shall be eleven. Do not continue to WP12, and WPX3 is right out).

Unfortunatly, since WP11 is 20+ years old, it's a miracle it's run with current operating systems. It runs fine on Win7 with XP-SP3 compatibility as administrator, but in Win10 with the same settings it fails.

Is there a way to diagnose this?

Comment: I have no problem running WP11 on my Windows 10 machine

Comment: @Ramhound, any special settings required, or the OP needs to diagnose some other cause?  I haven't touched Win 10, but does it have a compatibility setting going back to XP?

Comment: Maybe since Raymond's works on his Win10, it's a settings issue? Try less settings?